# How to fix this python error ' ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' '?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, collections, python-3.6

I downloaded a data mining project from GitHub and according to the requirements.txt file of this project, I downloaded all the required packages. (It should be noted that the Python version used for this project is version 3.6, but my version is 3.11.)

Anyway, after running the `python app.py`, I encountered this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\p\Desktop\Movie-Genre-Prediction-Deployment-master\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
  File "C:\Users\p\Desktop\Movie-Genre-Prediction-Deployment-master\virt_mgpdm\Lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jinja2 import escape
  File "C:\Users\p\Desktop\Movie-Genre-Prediction-Deployment-master\virt_mgpdm\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
  File "C:\Users\p\Desktop\Movie-Genre-Prediction-Deployment-master\virt_mgpdm\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 16, in <module>
    from jinja2.defaults import BLOCK_START_STRING, \
  File "C:\Users\p\Desktop\Movie-Genre-Prediction-Deployment-master\virt_mgpdm\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\defaults.py", line 32, in <module>
    from jinja2.tests import TESTS as DEFAULT_TESTS
  File "C:\Users\p\Desktop\Movie-Genre-Prediction-Deployment-master\virt_mgpdm\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\tests.py", line 13, in <module>
    from collections import Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

I should add that I upgraded the `Jinja2` package, which might solve the problem, but I encountered an error of incompatibility of the package with the project.

what should I do?

Comment: If you search the Python docs you will find out that the class was moved. Maybe downgrade your Python version?

Answer (score 2):

For `Python 3.10+` it should be:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
```

*for backward compatibility (if you have older versions of python) you can also do:*

```
try:
    from collections.abc import Mapping
except ImportError:
    from collections import Mapping
```